# Setting up Git in OSX: Error when generating an SSH rsa key pair "Could not create directory-Operation not permitted"

Tags: macos, git, ssh

I am trying to set up git in OSX using [these instructions](http://help.github.com/mac-set-up-git/).

When I try to generate a new SSH key

```
$ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "myemail@myemail.com"
```

I get "could not create directory '/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa': Operation not permitted"

I have tried repairing disk permission and tried searching but all the other people that have ran into a similar issue were using Windows.

Comment: Is your user name really 'user'?

Comment: for  'users/user/.ssh' do you mean  '/Users/user/.ssh' and user replaced by your login?

Comment: No my username isn't user, and my email isn't myemail@myemail.com.

Yes, user is replaced by my user name.

Comment: and the first / at the beginning

Comment: What about the / at the beginning?

Comment: So what are the permissions on /Users/user/.ssh or if that doesn't exist, /Users/user? Are you running the command as `user` (what's the output of `id` and `echo $HOME`)?

Comment: 'user' has admin privileges 


echo $HOME produces /Users/user

Answer (score 0):

Per the original poster:

> I fixed the problem by unlocking and gaining full write permission using: `chflags nouchg ~`